# Select menu option with selenium on click

Tags: python, html, selenium, drop-down-menu

I have the following HTML selectable menu (where you cannot click the second option until you click the `@id=category` menu) I am trying to navigate with Chrome headless browser using Selenium:

```
<div id="category" data-filters="Reports,Announcements" class="filter-form active">
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="filter-label">Category</span>
  <button aria-haspopup="dialog" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="categoryContent" data-initial-name="Category" class="filter-values" aria-label="Category">Category</button>
  <div class="styled-select-icon arrow" aria-expanded="true"></div>
  <button aria-label="Clear Category filter" class="styled-select-icon cross"></button>
  <div id="categoryContent" role="dialog" class="filter-form-labels filter-form-labels-wide">
      <strong class="small-only">Category<button aria-label="Close filter" class="close-btn close-filter-form">x</button></strong>
      <div class="inner">
        <div>
         <input type="checkbox" id="Reports">
         <label for="Reports" data-filtergroup="category" data-value="Reports">Reports</label>
        </div>
        <div>
         <input type="checkbox" id="Announcements">
         <label for="Announcements" data-filtergroup="category" data-value="Announcements">Announcements</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Edit: here is my driver instantiation:

```
    path_driver =  'chromedriver'
    chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument(("User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36"))
    chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_driver,options=chrome_options)
```

I believe I am able to select the menu that gives the option `id="category` with the following line of code:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='category']" ))))
```

but I cannot figure out how to select the input `Reports`:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='Reports']" ))))
```

when I try i just get a timeout error with a blank error message:

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Have you set the window-size in headless mode?

Comment: Yes, already have: `chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')`

Answer (score 0):

If you set with window-size() in headless mode.

Try click on `label` element instead `input`

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='Reports']" ))))
```

Comment: I did already try that and got the same blank timeout error.